# how to check row already exist in repeating table in infopath?

Tags: infopath-2007

Hello
I have repeating table on my infopath form. It is bound with xml file through web service. my form have submit button. I am able to submit data from infopath for to xml document via web service. I want to validate my repeating table to avoid duplicate records. how to do this validation. ? please guide me I am new for this.

Comment: in fact I want to check the current inserting row in already exist in repeating table or not. this is the core things. so expecting guidance to your Junior somehow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use validation rule.

1. You must select specific field of repeating table.
2. Add validation rule to it.
3. Select the expression and add rule:

   ```
    ../my:fzScopeName = ../preceding-sibling::my:fzItem/my:fzScopeName
   ```

   or

   ```
   ../my:fzScopeName = ../following-sibling::my:fzItem/my:fzScopeName
   ```

Note that: My field name is `fzScopeName` and `fzItem` is parent it, as same repeating table structure. [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wjbX.jpg)